# Integral approximation of $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-2)^j}{\exp j }$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

Consider the following summation:
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-2)^j}{\exp j }\approx 0.57611688476$$

Is there a way to convert this summation to an integral?

**motivation** the [tool](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) I'm using has better support for numeric integration than for summation, so trying to learn how to convert [similar kinds](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250687/accurately-computing-sum-j-2-infty-frac-xjj-zetaj) of alternating series to integrals. *Edit* I actually need to convert $\sum_{j=2}^\infty \frac{(-x)^j}{j!}\zeta(j)$ to an integral, but figured I should learn how to do the simple ones first.

Comment: This is a simple convergent geometric series. Is there any reason to convert it into an integral instead of a closed form answer? EDIT: I see the summation in the link doesn't have a simple closed form.

Comment: Yeah, why isn’t this just $\frac{e}{e+2}?$

Comment: It's tough, depending on the aliasing you want to introduce you could use $(-1)^j \mapsto \cos(\pi x)$ or $\cos(3\pi x)$, etc. There is probably an optimal frequency to choose since the lowest one may disproportionately weight close to constant portions of your function and taking the frequency to infinity disproportionately weights high gradient portions.

Comment: There are multiple ways you could convert this into an integral- such as using Abel summation, the Abel-Plana formula or multiplying by the gamma function’s main integral representation and moving the sum inside and just dividing by the gamma function on the outside, just to name a few methods.

Answer (score 1):

The rough estimate would be to split into positive and negative parts, and treat each one as Riemann sum.

$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-2)^j}{\exp j } = \int \frac{4^j}{e^{2j}} \mathrm d j-\frac{2}{e}\int\frac{4^j}{e^{2j}} \mathrm d j + 0.145550338...$$

Comment: but this kind of split didn't work for $\sum_{j=2}^\infty \frac{(-x)^j}{j!}\zeta(j)$ https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-katsurda-split.nb